# How can I declare what class a YAML.load() will return so that my IDE will properly identify the loaded object in inspections?

Tags: ruby, ide, rubymine, code-inspection, intellij-inspections

I have a class, `JsonConnection`. I serialize an instance of that class, `connection`, to YAML, and store it:

```rb
connection = JsonConnection.new
session[:con] = connection.to_yaml
```

Later, I use the `JsonConnection` deserialized from the storage throughout my code:

```rb
def con
  if session[:con]
    YAML.load(session[:con])
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, doing things this way means that RubyMine can't seem to tell what class of object `con` is, and so my code is littered with inspection problems:

[image: Screenshot of inspection issues]

Is there a way I can explictly declare that my `YAML.load()` returns a `JsonConnection` so that my IDE will be able to identify it properly?

Comment: I don't use RubyMine, so I haven't tried this, but did you take a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25455873/2981429

Comment: what does the `JsonConnection` class look like? you can declare ruby objects in yml files and load them as the given object via `YAML.dump` and `YAML.load` given that the constructors are correct to support this [Here](https://skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/) is a fairly old but still germane example